# errors in apply lm regression to each row

Tags: r, apply

I want to run a `lm` regression to each row of my data `dt`.
My code is

```
coe <- apply(dt, 1, FUN = function(x) lm(dbl ~ bld, data = as.data.frame(x))$coefficients)
```

But it returns:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'dbl' not found

I confirm that there are `dbl` and `bld` in my data `dt`.
So I do not know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have mistakenly written about running regression by row (which is impossible since there will just be one observation for `x` and `y` in `y ~ x`). Instead, you want to run the regression repeatedly for some grouping variable?

This is pretty easy to do with `groupedstats`:

```r
groupedstats::grouped_lm(
  data = ggplot2::diamonds,
  grouping.vars = c(cut, color),            # grouping variables
  formula = price ~ carat * clarity         # formula
)
#> # A tibble: 547 x 10
#>    cut   color term  estimate std.error  t.value conf.low conf.high
#>    <ord> <ord> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 Ideal E     (Int~  -3085.       64.9  -47.5    -3212.    -2958. 
#>  2 Ideal E     carat  10529.       74.1  142.     10384.    10674. 
#>  3 Ideal E     clar~  -2088.      267.    -7.81   -2612.    -1564. 
#>  4 Ideal E     clar~    168.      265.     0.633   -352.      688. 
#>  5 Ideal E     clar~   -926.      217.    -4.26   -1352.     -500. 
#>  6 Ideal E     clar~    625.      157.     3.99     318.      932. 
#>  7 Ideal E     clar~   -392.      107.    -3.65    -602.     -181. 
#>  8 Ideal E     clar~     83.9      79.1    1.06     -71.1     239. 
#>  9 Ideal E     clar~    -40.8      67.4   -0.605   -173.       91.4
#> 10 Ideal E     cara~   9746.      287.    34.0     9185.    10308. 
#> # ... with 537 more rows, and 2 more variables: p.value <dbl>,
#> #   significance <chr>
```

Created on 2018-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is the regression repeat within the grouping variables?

Comment: If there is just one grouping variable, then regression will be carried for all **levels** of that grouping variable. If there are multiple grouping variables, then the regression will be carried out for all possible **combinations**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with what you're trying to do. When you're passing `dt` to `apply`, it drops `x` to a (named) numeric vector. When you coerce it using `as.data.frame`, it becomes a data.frame with one column. This is why `dbl` is not found.

```
> x <- c(a = 1, b = 0.58)
> as.data.frame(x)
     x
a 1.00
b 0.58
```

Second point is that you want to do a regression on two points. In essence, you are doing this:

```
> lm(b ~ a, data = data.frame(a = 1, b = 0.58))

Call:
lm(formula = b ~ a, data = data.frame(a = 1, b = 0.58))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            a  
       0.58           NA
```

You will not be able to estimate the parameter of interest because you'll need more points to do that.